# Need a formula to find the nearest date/time based on a matching criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

1. Hello, I’m pretty new to excel and need a bit of help. In the Delivered tab I need to populate columns Answered and Date/Time Answered with the Answered and Date/Time columns in the Calls tab based on matching the ID from the Delivered tab to the ID in the Calls tab. For example: for the first row: ID: C763G. I should be getting M for the Answered column and 8/19/2021  11:29:00 PM for the Date/Time Delivered column. The correct returns for row 1 are highlighted in yellow. But I need to be able to do this for the rest of the rows.

Delivered tab
[image: Delivered tab]

Calls tab
[image: Calls tab]

I have tried a variety of combination of index, match, min etc. This one

```
=INDEX(Calls!D2:D26,MATCH(MIN(ABS((Calls!B2:B26=B2)*(Calls!C2:C26-C2))),ABS((Calls!B2:B26=B2)*(Calls!C2:C26-C2)),0))
```

Gave the wrong result. Y instead of M. Using the same formula but changing the indexed column to the column for the date/time it gave me 11/29/2019  12:39:36 AM, the wrong date and time instead of 8/19/2021  11:29:00 PM, the right one.

I had also tried

```
=IFERROR(SMALL(IF((Calls!B2:B26=B2)*(Calls!C2:C26<=C2),Calls!C2:C26),1),"No Match")
```

and

```
=MIN(IF((Calls!B2:B26=B2)*(Calls!C2:C26<=C2),Calls!C2:C26))
```

But that again gave me the wrong results.

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: Check my answer, I tested with mock up data, since you didn't provide the data in Table markdown format so we can copy it. Please next time take that into consideration. You can use the following [tool](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#), just copy the data from excel, generate it and copy it to your question. There is some caveat to consider, since the scenario needs some clarifications. Check it and let me know. Thanks

Comment: I second the point about ability to download data. But we also seem to be missing some precision about what the rule for matching. I initially thought this was a trivial VLOOKUP on the ID, but then see that C763G appears more than once in each sheet. So will the dates (but not times) always match, or be within 1 day? If not, what is the rule?

Comment: Does the requirement enable you to sort by ID, then Time? That would make a big difference if each ID gets reused once delivered.

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDEX(Dates,MATCH(MIN(ABS(Criteria-DateTimes)),ABS(Criteria-DateTimes),0))
```

Comment: I think you need to filter by the ID too, the `MIN` condition is taking into account the dates only I would say.

Answer (score 0):

Here you cannot use an approximate search via `XMATCH/MATCH` for example, because the nearest could be in both directions, greater/lower than, so we need to go finding the minimum of the absolute differences. It cannot be used `MAXIFS`, because it is a [RACON function](https://exceljet.net/articles/excels-racon-functions) and at the time we invoke an operation in the range, such as `ABS`, it is not a range anymore.

Here is an array version (*formula 1*), it generates the entire result, *assuming for any lookup **ID** you can find data* (if this assumption is not valid, check *formula 2* below).

```
=LET(lk, A2:B4, in, A9:C13,lkA, INDEX(lk,,1), lkB,INDEX(lk,,2),inA,INDEX(in,,1), 
 inB, INDEX(in,,2), out, CHOOSECOLS(in,2,3), dates, MAP(lkA, lkB, LAMBDA(id,d, 
 LET(f, FILTER(inB, inA=id), XLOOKUP(MIN(ABS(d-f)), ABS(d-f), f)))), 
 CHOOSEROWS(out, XMATCH(dates, inB)))
```

Since the date to find can be an exact match, we cannot use, the following:

```
FILTER(out, (inA=id) * (ABS(d-inB) = MIN((inA=id) * ABS(d-inB)))
```

because there is not way to distinguish when the minimum difference is zero because it is an exact match from the case the minimum value was found for a the subset that is not equal to `id`. That is why we go with `XLOOKUP`. Here is the output:

[image: output1]

Basically what is does is on each `MAP` iteration, it filters first to find the subset of dates for a given `id` (and name it `f`). Now we find the date with the minimum differences with respect to `d` for that specific subset. The result of `MAP` is named `dates`. Finally we just need to identify the rows that match the dates found. We use `CHOOSEROWS` for that, but you can also use `INDEX` as follows: `INDEX(out, XMATCH(d, inB),{1,2})` it is a matter of personal preferences.

For the case that there is no data for a given lookup **ID**. For example the row `5` (**ID** is `D`) from the lookup data in the previous screenshot (notice in *formula 1* the range ends at row `4`), the `formula 1` produces an error. In order to prevent it, for a more general case you can use the following (*formula 2*):

```
=LET(lk,A2:B5,in,A9:C13,lkA,INDEX(lk,,1),lkB, INDEX(lk,,2),inA,INDEX(in,,1), 
 inB, INDEX(in,,2), out, CHOOSECOLS(in,2,3), dates, MAP(lkA, lkB, LAMBDA(id,d, 
 LET(f,FILTER(inB,inA=id,""),IF(@f="", "",XLOOKUP(MIN(ABS(d-f)),ABS(d-f),f))))),
 IF(dates="", {"ID not Found",""}, INDEX(out, XMATCH(dates, inB),{1,2})))
```

Here we check for an empty set of `FILTER` using the third input argument of this function, so in case of error it returns the empty string. The condition: `IF(@f="", "",...)` treats this situation specially returning an empty set too. Then to return the output we use an `IF` condition to treat this case as `"ID not found"`. The rest is about the same. Note: Here we need to use `INDEX`, because `CHOOSEROWS` produces an error.

Here is the output:

[image: output2]

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that the requirement is to match by ID and day, although the Delivery might be the day after the Call (across midnight)
And that a given ID is not reused within a day.

In Calls, insert a rowA to the left (because VLOOKUP can only look to the right, not the left.
In A2 enter `=C2&"_"&INT(D2)` and drag down.
That gives us a key against which to match.
In Delivered we can do the extra off to the right.
In G2 enter `=$B2&"_"&INT($C2)` and in H2 enter `=$B2&"_"&INT($C2)-1` and drag down.
We are looking up from the Delivered(note 1) so the Call might be one day *earlier*.
Then in E2 `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($G2,Calls!$A:$E,4,FALSE),VLOOKUP($H2,Calls!$A:$E,4,FALSE))` i.e. try to match on ID and date; if no match try ID and previous day.
Copy that formula to D2, and change the 4s to 5s.
Drag down.

Note 1: Actually I suggest you think about whether that is appropriate - you will miss any Calls without Deliveries which are more likely to exist than the other way round.

Note 2: The $ are not strictly necessary, but they reduce the risk of error especially if copying further.

Note 3: The "_"& are not strictly necessary but help readability and therefore reduce the chances of errors.